# Application error client side exception: Next js React app only on production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, production-environment

i see an issue only with IE browser and  DJ Browser for the nextjs  react UI app that is running on production.

It always throws application error client side exception randomly every day. at least 1000 times a day.

The error that i see on the console is pretty absurd.  It says:

> Object eroor: unpecified error At anonymous function
> (https://breaker.pk/_next/static/chunks/main-47f8tfdf6635vg875.js)

Things i tried to fix the code:
1.added necessary response?.object checks to handle undefined.
2.added necessary await async handlers for external calls.

What could be the root cause?